# Cayley-Dickson Construction

Tags: complex-numbers

Assume $A$ is an algebra with involution $*$, and it has a norm $|x|=\sqrt{x^*x}$, which satisfies $|x||y|\geq|xy|$.

By Cayley-Dickson construction, we have an algebra $B=A\times A$, which satisfies
$$(p,q)(r,s)=(pr-s^*q,sp+qr^*)$$
$$(p,q)^*=(p^*,-q)$$
$$|(p,q)|=\sqrt{p^*p+q^*q}$$

My  question is that does the norm $|\cdot|$ satisfy
$$|(p,q)||(r,s)|\geq|(p,q)(r,s)|$$

---

From the property of $A$, we have

- $\sqrt{a^*a}+\sqrt{b^*b}\geq\sqrt{(a+b)*(a+b)}$
- $\sqrt{a^*a}\sqrt{b^*b}\geq\sqrt{(ab)^*ab}$

Then we need to prove 
$$(p^*p+q^*q)(r^*r+s^*s)\geq(pr-s^*q)^*(pr-s^*q)+(sp+qr^*)^*(sp+qr^*)$$
Or
$$p^*pr^*r+p^*ps^*s+q^*qr^*r+q^*qs^*s$$
$$\geq r^*p^*pr+q^*ss^*q+p^*s^*sp+rq^*qr^*-r^*p^*s^*q-q^*spr+p^*s^*qr^*+rq^*sp$$

I have no idea to prove this inequality. And maybe this is not always true. Can some give some advice to prove it or find a counterexample? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sixteen dimensional Cayley-Dickson algebra--the sedenions--D. Bliss, J. Christensen, D. Dugger and D. Isaksen showed that $|xy|\le\sqrt{2}|x|\cdot|y|$ and that if $0\le t\le \sqrt{2}$ then there exist sedenians $x,y$ such that $|xy|=t|x|\cdot|y|$. They also derived a general inequality depending upon the dimension of the algebra. The paper is "Eigentheory of Cayley-Dickson algebras" in Forum Mathematicum, vol 21, No. 5, pp. 833-851. (2009) You can see an example of two sedenions for which $t=\sqrt{2}$ on my website at http://jwbales.us/sedenion.html.